# EaselJS export DisplayObject as bitmap

Tags: easeljs

I have a [EaselJS `Container` object](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Container.html) and I want to export its contents (children `Bitmaps`) as an image (similar to what you would do with ActionScript `PNGEncoder.encode`).

Is this possible? I have other object present that I don't want to export so exporting the full `<canvas>` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `getCacheDataURL` method to export any *cached* DisplayObject to an image data url.

http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/jqfgynve/1/

```
bmp.cache(0,0,image.width,image.height);
var url = bmp.getCacheDataURL();
var img = new Image();
img.src = url;
```

Any time you cache an image, a canvas is created that is drawn in place of the image. This method calls `toDataURL()` on the cache-canvas, generating a data URL that can be passed to the source of an image.

Note that the toDataURL is not a super performant API.

Comment: great! this works. i'd like to add to anyone reading this that you might want to `uncache()` after you're done saving and might also need to replace the container with a fresh new instance: `bmp.uncache(); bmp = new createjs.Container();`